# Formatting tables inside minipage

Tags: tables, minipage, fbox

I want to create a document with three tables inside minipage environments. See MWE below.

While I do get three tables side by side, the contents of these tables overlap. One way to get rid of these could be if the longer cells get line break inside a cell.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
        OT goods for CA-GB
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.9pt}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ lr }
                Inj Stacef-1g           & 2 \\ 
                Disposable syringes-5ml & 5 \\  
                Shi mediwear gown       & 5 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
                
    \end{minipage}%
}
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
        OT goods for CA-GB
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.9pt}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ lr }
                Inj Stacef-1g           & 2 \\ 
                Disposable syringes-5ml & 5 \\  
                Shi mediwear gown       & 5 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
                
    \end{minipage}%
}
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
        OT goods for CA-GB
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.9pt}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ lr }
                Inj Stacef-1g           & 2 \\ 
                Disposable syringes-5ml & 5 \\  
                Shi mediwear gown       & 5 
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
                
    \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I keep these three tables side by side, yet avoid overlapping? Any workaround or a complete new way to achieve this?

Comment: lr are both single line entries so you either need to use a smaller font size or change l to `p{2cm}` or whatever width you want. This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options/332903#332903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables can be enhanced in many way. This is one possibility to fit the three tables without changing the font size. The `\arraystretch` expands the cell vertically. The `\multirow` in the first line enhances the title.
The type `P` column allows for longer sentences in a fixed width cell, as in the second line.

The `\tabcolsep` controls the separation between the two columns. You might play with different values of `\tabcolsep` and the width of the minipage.

[image: abc]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}    
    \begin{tabular}{|P{1} c|}  
        \hline        
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{OT goods for CA-GB}}  \\ 
                                & \\
             \hline 
        Inj Stacef-1g           & 2\\ 
        Disposable syringes-5ml & 5\\  
        Shi mediwear gown       & 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}              
\end{minipage}\hfill  
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}    
    \begin{tabular}{|P{1} c|}  
        \hline        
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{OT goods for CA-GB}}  \\ 
                                &\\
        \hline 
        Inj Stacef-1g           & 2\\ 
        Disposable syringes-5ml & 5\\  
        Shi mediwear gown       & 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}    
\end{minipage}\hfill  
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}    
    \begin{tabular}{|P{1} c|}  
        \hline        
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{OT goods for CA-GB}}  \\ 
                                &\\
        \hline 
        Inj Stacef-1g           & 2\\ 
        Disposable syringes-5ml & 5\\  
        Shi mediwear gown       & 5 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}    
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```